# SQL special characters JSP

Tags: sql, jsp

I am having some trouble while searching the Database for some strings with special characters through JSP.

eg:

```
col name       obj_id
value          blah/blah[blah]
```

and I  have got to search it dynamically through JSP, eg:

```
select * 
from table 
where objid like '" +obj_id+ "'**
```

this query works for normal strings. Please can anyone tell me how to make it work for special characters as well?

I read up on that escape `{ escape '/' }` bit. Can that be included here? If so, how?

Comment: Stop executing queries from JSPs. Learn prepared statements. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Suppose I have just this one  statement to execute , then can you help me?  I know prepared statements.

Comment: Then use them instead of concatenating.

Comment: they will work for special characters as well?

Comment: Test if you can run your SQL statement against the database using the databases query tool...like Sql Server Management Studio or whatever tool you use to query your database. If you can query it that way, you'll likely be able to query it via JDBC

Comment: Use a PreparedStatement - even if you only execute this once. Using prepared statements isn't only about performance, it's also about proper parameter passing and protection against SQL injection.

Comment: @MrMoose- yes the query is working fine with hardcoded values,offline.
But while passing hardcoded values in JDBC itself like 

like 'blah/blah' .Its not working . :/

Comment: Also, "not working" doesn't mean anything. Be clear and precise. Define what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Show the code and the inputs and the outputs.

Comment: @JBNizet Ohkay .Wait ,I will upload it

Comment: `String id_no=request.getParameter("id_no");
query1="select    * from table_case where table_case.id_no = 'blah...///blah' "; `